# Media queries for large screen are being overridden by the smaller media queries

Tags: html, css

[Here is the link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/secyr/h816ub2s/3/)

I have

```
    .hydrocarbons {
    float: left;
    width: 85.25%;
    }
  
    .claymore {
    float:  left;
    clear: right;
    }
```

in the medium @media, and

```
    .hydrocarbons {
    width: 91.67%;
    }
```

in the smallest @media.

In the medium view, everything works as its supposed to, display is normal, not overridden by the smallest @media. But the large view is happily overridden by the medium @media, and I cannot figure out why this is happening. The media queries are written largest to smallest.

Thanks

Comment: try changing '@media screen and (min-width: 768px), (max-width: 991px)' to '@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)' - note the "and" instead of the comma

Answer (score 0):

Large screen like laptops/ desktops. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){.div{width: 1px;}}
```

Small screen like mobiles. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px){.div{width: 1px;}}
```

You can use `!important;` to override but not recommended unless absolutely necessary.